# Can't Get KDE on chromebook

Tags: kde, chromebook

While atepmting to install kde on my chromebook i got this message I: Retrieving Release 
W: Retrying failed download of http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release     then E: Failed getting release file http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu releases**

The Saucy 'end of life' day was: July 17, 2014 - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Try current releases: Precise, Trusty, Utopic, Vivid